# How to communicate with Firefox using C++?

Tags: c++, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am on project right now which is a very simple parental control software, but, I want to know what is the url requested in firefox to take respond based on it ... if you may help because I don't know how to let my software know what is the url requested by firefox .. How to do that?
I have to use C++ in most of my software.. but if there are better language to do this task please advice me

Comment: If this question is about `[java]` can you include your Java code?

Comment: People stop down voting this guy, these are important questions. It's vague because he needs some direction. Help him with that, a down vote doesn't help groom new members to the community. If he was an established member I would understand the downvotes, but immediately when the kid signs up you're down votes are not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox you need to use XPCOM component called nsIHTTPChannel. This script below will block abort all rqeuests to google. The channel is opened but aborted before opening connection to server.

```
var {classes: Cc, results: Cr, utils: Cu} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

var httpRequestObserver = 
{
    observe: function(subject, topic, data)
    {
        var httpChannel, requestURL;

        if (topic == 'http-on-modify-request') {
            httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            requestURL = httpChannel.URI.spec;

            if (/google\.com/.test(requestURL)) {
                httpChanel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
            }

            return;
        }
    }
};

Services.obs.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, 'http-on-modify-request', false);
//Services.obs.removeObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-modify-request", false); //run this to remove observer
```

Comment: Thank you all very much .. your answers were very usefull

Comment: my pleasure man. i realize you arent making a firefox addon though. if you want a working template of an addon that uses this method let me know

Comment: but as i understod that the XPCOM code you gave will abort the rqeuests to google? am I right? but, i need my software to get the url requested by firefox and then it will use db containing not allowed urls then if someone requested url not allowed the software will take an action like closing the browser and olaying wave alert file

Comment: yes it will. but its not a complete addon. you have pack it as xpi and include rdf. are you making an addon or is this all the code that u'll need?

Comment: dear sir, I am totally new for web browser based softwares so I hope that this answer will help you to advice me: Let's say that x man required an url using firefox i want firefox to pass this url to my software to take decisions .. something maybe like what happend when you download something using IDM.. So is the add on as i undestand is the way to communicate with firefox.. but how to pass the requested url to my software?? maybe writing it to txt fle or is there better way? I am sure you may find my question is a little bit stupid but as i told i am totally new to web based apps

Comment: ah you dont need a firefox adddon. you need to just listen to all packets on the OS like user267345 below recommended. if u create a firefox addon you introduce an unnecssary layer

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest an alternative approach? Instead of writing an extension for Firefox and an extension for Chrome and an extension for IE... listen on the OS network interfaces for traffic and block undesirable URLS.

This is traditionally the job of a firewall. Using an existing solution will provide the most efficient means of solving your problem. I'm not familiar with the capabilities of the built in Windows firewall or 3rd party alternatives but something like this would be trivial with iptables (Linux).

Comment: Thank youa lot, I am going to discuss this method with the meant persons